# firestore get field to function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So i made a question earlier on getting a field from firestore.
And its working correctly within the logs.

But im trying to find a way to set the get name of my code
to a function

here is the code

```
db.collection('users').doc('' + sender_id).get().then(doc=>{
    if (!doc.exists) {
        console.log('No Such document exists');
    }
    // do stuff with data smiley face.
    (doc.data().name);
    console.log('So it got your name correctly' + doc.data().name);
}).catch(err=>{
    console.error('error getting document', err);
    process.exit();
});
```

and here is how I would like to implement it.

```
function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(+Getname + `,
    Welcome to my chat bot.`);
}
```

So I would presume wrapping the first code in a

```
const getname = "firstcodehere";
```

but I presume it's not as easy as that as iv tried multiple times. with no luck.
there must be an easy way to reuse the first code in multiple instances with just a constant name.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out there is little ways out of this issue but to wrap the entire code within this function so that it returns the info directly.

then you can use a const "something" = doc.data().name;

so you can then use + something + ' is your name right? '

thanks for all the help. :) hope this answer helps others in the future.